# Fast equivalent to sin() for DSP referenced in STK

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, signal-processing

I'm using bits of Perry Cook's Synthesis Toolkit (STK) to generate saw and square waves. STK includes this BLIT-based sawtooth oscillator:

```
inline STKFloat BlitSaw::tick( void ) {
  StkFloat tmp, denominator = sin( phase_ );
  if ( fabs(denominator) <= std::numeric_limits<StkFloat>::epsilon() )
      tmp = a_;
  else {
      tmp = sin( m_ * phase_ );
      tmp /= p_ * denominator;
  }

  tmp += state_ - C2_;
  state_ = tmp * 0.995;

  phase_ += rate_;
  if ( phase_ >= PI ) 
     phase_ -= PI;

  lastFrame_[0] = tmp;
     return lastFrame_[0];
}
```

The square wave oscillator is broadly similar. At the top, there's this comment:

```
// A fully  optimized version of this code would replace the two sin 
// calls with a pair of fast sin oscillators, for which stable fast 
// two-multiply algorithms are well known.
```

I don't know where to start looking for these "fast two-multiply algorithms" and I'd appreciate some pointers. I could use a lookup table instead, but I'm keen to learn what these 'fast sin oscillators' are. I could also use an abbreviated Taylor series, but thats way more than two multiplies. Searching hasn't turned up anything much, although I did find this approximation:

```
#define AD_SIN(n) (n*(2.f- fabs(n)))
```

Plotting it out shows that it's not really a close approximation outside the range of -1 to 1, so I don't think I can use it when `phase_` is in the range -pi to pi:

[image: Plot of Sine vs. approximation]

Here, Sine is the blue line and the purple line is the approximation.

Profiling my code reveals that the calls to `sin()` are far and away the most time-consuming calls, so I really would like to optimise this piece.

Thanks

**EDIT** Thanks for the detailed and varied answers. I will explore these and accept one at the weekend.

**EDIT 2** Would the anonymous close voter please kindly explain their vote in the comments? Thank you.

Comment: I'm surprised that a sawtooth oscillator requires trigonometric calculations.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth, they shouldn't. Ideal square-tooth & saw-tooth oscillators are easily modeled with simple algebra. My guess is maybe they're try to model less-ideal physical oscillators. For a saw-tooth, this is generally done as a sum of sine waves.

Comment: @NathanErnst the reason you use these functions isn't to do with modelling physical oscillators. Instead, it is because a 'pure' saw wave has infinite harmonics. Any harmonics above half the sampling frequency (44100/2) cause aliasing effects which sound absolutely dreadful. This technique here generates a 'band limited', or anti aliased sawtooth where the harmonics are controlled.

Comment: @Tim: That only happens if you're downsampling without an anti-aliasing filter. You can't, by definition, generate the harmonics above the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Of course it's possible to generate spectrum way above "Nyquist", as in undersampling a sufficiently band-limited high frequency signal (and reconstructing by the converse).  When not band-limited, however, this is usually just called noise, which a ideal low-pass filtered triangle or square wave is trying to eliminate.

Comment: @hotpaw2: You're right, I was ignoring undersampling type applications.  But assuming the OP is feeding his sample values with a baseband DAC, then my statement holds.  Of course, if you're dealing with a sub-optimal reconstruction filter, then there are other considerations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially the sinusoidal oscilator is one (or more) variables that change with each DSP step, rather than getting recalculated from scratch.

The simplest are based on the following trig identities: (where `d` is constant, and thus so is `cos(d)` and `sin(d)` )

```
sin(x+d) = sin(x) cos(d) + cos(x) sin(d)
cos(x+d) = cos(x) cos(d) - sin(x) sin(d)
```

However this requires two variables (one for sin and one for cos) and 4 multiplications to update. However this will still be far faster than calculating a full sine at each step.

The solution by Oli Charlesworth is based on solutions to this general equation

```
A_{n+1} = a A_{n} + A_{n-1}
```

Where looking for a solution of the form `A_n = k e^(i theta n)` gives an equation for `theta`.

```
e^(i theta (n+1) ) = a e^(i theta n ) + b e^(i theta (n-1) )
```

Which simplifies to

```
e^(i theta) - e^(-i theta ) = a
2 cos(theta) = a
```

Giving

```
A_{n+1} = 2 cos(theta) A_{n} + A_{n-1}
```

Whichever approach you use you'll either need to use one or two of these oscillators for each frequency, or use another trig identity to derive the higher or lower frequencies.

Comment: +1. I remember seeing something like this by Steve Hollasch. (http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/inccos.html).

Comment: I am getting my head round this slowly. I understand the concept of the sin oscillator now and how it replaces full sin() calls in the code above. @BrettHale's link has proven very useful too. Let me bed it down in my brain a bit more and figure out how to fit it into the saw oscillator code I already have. I'll get back to you either with questions or an accept. Thanks for your time here.

Answer (score 3):

How accurate do you need this?

This function, f(x)=0.398x*(3.1076-|x|), does a reasonably good job for x between -pi and pi.

**Edit**

An even better approximation is f(x)=0.38981969947653056*(pi-|x|), which keeps the absolute error to 0.038158444604 or less for x between -pi and pi.

A least squares minimization will yield a slightly different function.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you David; I'll try this one first. I'm not sure whether the domain of the second sine (`sin(m_ * phase)`) is also -pi to pi, but I see exactly how you reached the approximation and how it could be applied there also.

Comment: I tried running the approximation out a few more DPs (did this before I saw your edit above) but even then the results did not turn out usable. The error is, I think, just too large. The sound turned out to be a horrific, static-filled and bit-crushed nightmare. Nevertheless, this is an extremely useful and fast approximation which will have applications elsewhere, so thanks for posting it. I will try your revised approximation too.

Comment: This is great. You forgot an x in your second, better approximation, though. Does the constant have any special meaning?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to generate one-off sin calls with just two multiplies (well, not a useful approximation, at any rate).  But it is possible to generate an oscillator with low complexity, i.e. where each value is calculated in terms of the preceding ones.

For instance, consider that the following difference equation will give you a sinusoid:

```
y[n] = 2*cos(phi)*y[n-1] - y[n-2]
```

(where `cos(phi)` is a constant)

Comment: Thanks for this. Michael's answer gives some good context to help understand your answer. As a rank beginner with DSP I'm still at the stage where I need to be spoon-fed quite a bit. I appreciate your time on my question.

Answer (score 1):

(From the original author of the VST BLT code).

As a matter of fact, I was porting the VST BLT oscillators to C#, so I was googling for good sin oscillators. Here's what I came up with. Translation to C++ is straightforward. See the notes at the end about accuumulated round-off errors.

```
public class FastOscillator
{

    private double b1;
    private double y1, y2;

    private double fScale;

    public void Initialize(int sampleRate)
    {
        fScale = AudioMath.TwoPi / sampleRate;
    }
     // frequency in Hz. phase in radians.
    public void Start(float frequency, double phase)
    {
        double w = frequency * fScale;
        b1 = 2.0 * Math.Cos(w);
        y1 = Math.Sin(phase - w);
        y2 = Math.Sin(phase - w * 2);
    }
    public double Tick()
    {
        double y0 = b1 * y1 - y2;
        y2 = y1;
        y1 = y0;
        return y0;
    }
}
```

Note that this particular oscillator implementation will drift over time, so it needs to be re-initialzed periodically. In this particular implementation, the magnitude of the sin wave decays over time. The original comments in the STK code suggested a two-multiply oscillator. There are, in fact, two-multiply oscillators that are reasonably stable over time. But in retrospect, the need to keep the sin(phase), and sin(m*phase) oscillators tightly in synch probably means that they have to be resynched anyway. Round-off errors between phase and m*phase mean that even if the oscillators were stable, they would drift eventually, running a significant risk of producing large spikes in values near the zeros of the BLT functions. May as well use a one-multiply oscillator.

These particular oscillators should probably be re-initialized every 30 to 100 cycles (or so). My C# implementation is frame based (i.e. it calculates an float[] array of results in a void Tick(int count, float[] result) method. The oscillators are re-synched at the end of each Tick call. Something like this:

```
   void Tick(int count, float[] result)   
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
                ...
            result[i] = bltResult;
        }
        // re-initialize the oscillators to avoid accumulated drift.
        this.phase = (this.phase + this.dPhase*count) % AudioMath.TwoPi;
        this.sinOsc.Initialize(frequency,this.phase);
        this.mSinOsc.Initialize(frequency*m,this.phase*m);
   }
```

Probably missing from the STK code. You might want to investigate this. The original code provided to the STK did this. Gary Scavone tweaked the code a bit, and I think the optimization was lost. I do know that the STK implementations suffer from DC drift, which can be almost entirely eliminated when implemented properly.

There's a peculiar hack that prevents DC drift of the oscillators, even when sweeping the frequency of the oscillators. The trick is that the oscillators should be started with an initial phase adjustment of dPhase/2. That just so happens to start the oscillators off with zero DC drift, without having to figure out wat the correct initial state for various integrators in each of the BLT oscillators.

Strangely, if the adjustment is re-adjusted whenever the frequency of the oscillator changes, then this also prevents wild DC drift of the output when sweeping the frequency of the oscillator. Whenever the frequency changes, subtract dPhase/2 from the previous phase value, recalculate dPhase for the new frequency, and then add dPhase/2.I rather suspect this could be formally proven; but I have not been able to so. All I know is that It Just Works.

For a block implementation, the oscillators should actually be initialized as follows, instead of carrying the phase adjustment in the current this.phase value.

```
        this.sinOsc.Initialize(frequency,phase+dPhase*0.5);
        this.mSinOsc.Initialize(frequency*m,(phase+dPhase*0.5)*m);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look here:

http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/4648-fast-and-accurate-sinecosine/

There's some sample code that calculates a very good appoximation of sin/cos using only multiplies, additions and the abs() function.  Quite fast too.  The comments are also a good read.

It essentiall boils down to this:

```
float sine(float x)
{
    const float B = 4/pi;
    const float C = -4/(pi*pi);
    const float P = 0.225;    

    float y = B * x + C * x * abs(x);

    return P * (y * abs(y) - y) + y;
}
```

and works for a range of -PI to PI

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should consider memorization based techniques. Essentially store sin(x) and cos(x) values for a bunch values. To calculate sin(y), find a and b for which precomputed values exist such that  a<=y<=b. Now using sin(a), sin(b), cos(a), cos(b), y-a and y-b approximately calculate sin(y).

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of getting periodically sampled results from the sine or cosine function is to use a trig recursion or an initialized (barely) stable IIR filter (which can end up being pretty much the same computations).  There are bunches of these in the DSP literature, of varying accuracy and stability.  Choose carefully.